# can not ssh vm instance via browser

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine

I used to connect to VM instance (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS based) using ssh from browser by going to https://console.developers.google.com  then compute engine then VM instances and select the instance then click on the ssh button.

I stopped working on this instance for few days then when I came back I couldn't connect using ssh.

I thought the issue is in the instance itself , so I created new instance but couldn't connect to it too

I also tried this command

```
gcloud compute ssh tareq@jenkins-server-ubuntu --zone us-central1-c
```

but I get the following error

```
Server refused our key
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH to the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.
```

Do you have any idea why this happened and how can I fix this? there is tomcat server installed in the instance and I need to run it

Comment: What is your gcloud sdk version ? Are you running gcloud ssh command from windows machine ?

Comment: I am using gcloud Google Cloud SDK [91.0.1] on windows machine

please note that im not able to connect from the browser too , not only through gcloud command.

the ssh fails also on all instances on the same project and its working fine on other compute engine projects .

it seems that it is an issue on the cloud project configurations

Comment: Have you tried to do a 'Reset' on the instance first? I've had an instance lock up before where I couldn't ssh into it. But after resetting and waiting 30 seconds was able to get in.

Comment: There is number of troubleshooting tips at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser, did you see those?